# Center mark on google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I would like to add a center mark on the google maps api v3. This would be a mark with low opacity that is constantly in the center of the map. Here is my dilemma.

1. I cannot add it in an absolutely positioned div or image, with high z-index, outside of the map div because it would prevent clicking markers in the map div.
2. I cannot add it as a marker because it would would move with the map. I do not want to reposition it with the `dragend` event because it would still move during the drag.
3. I don't believe I can use an overlay because this would always move with the map. I could be wrong on this one.

Comment: I don't understand your objection to option 1.  Unless your mark image is as big as the map it will only interfere with marker clicks directly under the mark.

Comment: @EricBridger For my application, I sometimes center the marker of interest in the map, which would mean that I can no longer interact with that marker given an appreciably sized center mark.

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of these:

- Reposition marker on `bounds_changed` event's handler
- Reposition marker on `center_changed` event's handler